# Did Stalin give special treatment for his home country?

Tags: soviet-union, stalin

Did Stalin during his reign gave any special interest or priviliges to Georgia and the Georgian people?

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two things:

- There was a high number of people from the Caucasus area in his administration. I'm not sure it one would call it a privilege to come to Stalin's attention, but it was certainly special treatment.
- Stalin and those friends had palaces in the Caucasus. Those would have brought money into the local economy.

Answer (score 3):

From what I read in his biography, if anything he did the opposite. 
He hated his father, hated the church.
During his rule a lot of purges hit the Caucasus, including the complete removal of population groups to Siberia and replacing them with Russian natives.

He rarely even went back there, only a few times to visit his ailing mother (whom he adored) after installing her in what amounted to a palatial home for her.

Comment: Stalin was from Georgia, not Siberia.

Comment: @Bregalad so? I never said he was from Siberia...

Comment: @Bregalad _undesirables_ were removed to Siberia *from* Georgia. jwenting never said JS was from there.

Answer (score -1):

Georgians weren`t given special treatment just because Stalin was Georgian. The Georgian Soviet Socialist Republic was an ordinary Soviet republic among other Soviet republics.